# I try to return to resolve true of a promise and it does not work VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using the [vue-form-wizard](http://vuejs.creative-tim.com/vue-form-wizard) component ,   [In the documentation there is an example](http://vuejs.creative-tim.com/vue-form-wizard/#/?id=async-validation) with validation of the tabs using promises, I have managed to issue the event from the child component and on from the parent component. even if I make a console.log () before the promise it throws me the message correctly, then I do not know what is failing

I currently use vueJs, VueRouter

Child Component , emit event

```
methods :{
   selectItem : function(tipo,event){
       this.$router.app.$emit('eventoPersonalizadoOne',tipo)
   } /* others methods*/
}
```

Father Component

```
mounted() {
  this.$router.app.$on('eventoPersonalizadoOne', this.eventoPersonalizadoOne)
},
methods: {
        oneComplete:function() {
       //This function is in charge of validating, if true returns the promise to continue
          console.log("Hello World");//If it shows
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              resolve(true)
          })
        },
        eventoPersonalizadoOne(data){
            this.tipoSelect = data;
            //validate if it should continue to the next tab in the wizard
            this.oneComplete();
        }

    }
```

If I normally call the oneComplete function with the typical next button, it performs the correct validation, it only fails when I deal with `emmit` and `on` apparently

**Edit**

In mi `TabContent`

```
 <tab-content v-for="tab in tabs"
      v-if="!tab.hide"
      :key="tab.id"
      :title="tab.title"
      :before-change="tab.completed"        
       >
    <component :is="tab.component"></component>
 </tab-content>
```

These components are filled with an array of components

```
tabs: [
    {
        title: 'Tipo de Producto', 
        component: 'TipoProducto', 
        completed : this.oneComplete
    }, 
    {
        title: 'Cantidad de Producto', 
        component: 'CantidadProducto', 
        hide: false
    }, 
],
```

In my child component the selectItem event is called simply by pressing a button when I select the button, it is a signal that the validation to go to the next tab is made, but it does not do so. I have to give it in the next button of the wizard

```
<button v-for="item in items" class="col-md-3 col-5 col-sm-3 col-xl-2 col-lg-3 
                ml-sm-4 mr-sm-2 ml-md-3 ml-lg-3  ml-xl-4 mr-xl-4 ml-3 mt-2 alert alert-success numeros" role="alert" 
 @click="selectItem(item,$event)" v-html="item.descripcion">
```

Comment: Show your template. What do you have in `:before-change`?

Comment: @acdcjunior I have updated with the data requested

Comment: I don't think you will get what you want. To use promises, the method that is in `:before-change` (in your case `:before-change="tab.completed"`), is the one that must return a Promise. `$emit`s don't return promises.

Comment: So how could I do it correctly? Is not that possible, as I am proposing? Is there any other way? I do not want to have everything in one component

Comment: Via events, no, I don't think it is. Show the location where that `selectItem` method is used.

Comment: Correct, I added the use of the event is simply buttons, if the button is given it is because it is valid to continue to the next tab